# mySQL for SqlBulkCopy

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I am new to sql and vb.

I have the following code that works fine for MS SQL EXPRESS.

```
            If cboServer.Text = "MS SQL Express" Then
            Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(sCONN)
            sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 500

            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = sTable
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader)

        End If
```

However I am not trying to write the data into MySQL due to the data limitations of MS SQL.

Here is what I have, But I know it is wrong.

```
            If cboServer.Text = "MySQL" Then
            Dim MyConn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
            MyConn.ConnectionString = sCONN
            Dim mysqlBulk As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader(MyConn)


            mysqlBulk.TableName = sTable
            mysqlBulk.FileName = sFilename
            mysqlBulk.Load()



        End If
```

Below is the full mod.

```
  Private Sub ImportFromExcel(ByVal sFilename As String, ByVal sTable As String)

    Try
        Dim excelConnectionString As String = String.Empty

        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFilename & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False"

        Dim excelConnection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [" & sTable & "$]", excelConnection)

        excelConnection.Open()
        Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        If cboServer.Text = "MS SQL Express" Then
            Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(sCONN)
            sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 500

            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = sTable
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader)

        End If

        If cboServer.Text = "MySQL" Then
            Dim MyConn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
            MyConn.ConnectionString = sCONN
            Dim mysqlBulk As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader(MyConn)


            mysqlBulk.TableName = sTable
            mysqlBulk.FileName = sFilename
            mysqlBulk.Load()



        End If

        lstError.Items.Clear()
        lstError.Items.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(sFilename, 35) & " " & sTable)
        excelConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        lstError.Items.Add("Error Reading " & sFilename & " " & sTable)
        lstError.Items.Add(Err.Description)
        lstError.Items.Add("")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub
```

How do I get the MySQL part to load the data?

Comment: AFAIK the MySQL bulk loader is for importing CSVs.  If you have the data in a datatable you should be able to just insert it to either DB using a DataAdapter

Comment: Hi @Plutonix, This makes sense, I am not able to import CSV files with my code. The challenge is that my Excel file contains 4 sheets. So I assume that I need to open the file, write the data into CSV for the 1st sheet and then load the CSV, kill the CSV and then loop to the next sheet.

Comment: You could load from excel using OleDb then insert to MySql

Comment: @Plutonix, how would I do that? that is exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing and using a `DataTable` and `DataAdapter` does work and only takes about 10 lines of code.  But due to the nature of the DA, it is pretty slow: ~30 secs to process 10k rows.

Since both bulk tools will work with CSVs and are super fast, I would read in the XL file, export to CSV then use MySqlBulkLoader.  [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) makes the middle step easy.

```vb
Dim xlConStr = String.Format(OleXLConnstr, "C:\Temp\members.xls")
Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM [NewMembers$]"
Dim tmpCSVName = "C:\Temp\newmembers.csv"

Dim srcRows As Int32 = 0
Dim dstRows As Int32 = 0

' step one export to CSV - the LCD
Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(xlConStr),
    cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbcon)
    Using stw As New StreamWriter(tmpCSVName, False),
         csv = New CsvWriter(stw)

        ' my data can have embedded commas: "Ziggy T. Wilson, Esq."
        csv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = True

        dbcon.Open()
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                rdr.Read()
                ' write out the fieldnames as column headers
                For n As Int32 = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
                    csv.WriteField(rdr.GetName(n))
                Next
                csv.NextRecord()

                ' write the data
                Do
                    For n As Int32 = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
                        If rdr.GetFieldType(n) Is GetType(DateTime) Then
                            ' format dates to ISO
                            ' ToDo: add time as needed
                            csv.WriteField(rdr.GetDateTime(n).
                                                ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        Else
                            csv.WriteField(rdr(n))
                        End If
                    Next
                    srcRows += 1
                    csv.NextRecord()
                Loop While (rdr.Read() And rdr.IsDBNull(0) = False)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Dim bulk = New MySqlBulkLoader(dbcon)

    bulk.TableName = "Member"
    bulk.FieldTerminator = ","
    bulk.LineTerminator = "\r\n"    ' == CR/LF
    bulk.FileName = tmpCSVName      ' file path name to CSV 
    bulk.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1    ' has a header
    bulk.FieldQuotationOptional = False
    bulk.FieldQuotationCharacter = Convert.ToChar(34)

    dstRows = bulk.Load()
End Using
```

- For some reason `OleDB` is reading one more row than is actually in the XLS.  It does the same thing if you load a `DataTable`.  The `rdr.IsDBNull(0)` test in the loop control is to prevent adding such a row to the CSV by testing a column I know should not be blank.
- You can compare `srcRows` and `dstRows` to see if they were all imported.
- You will likely have some changes to make since we have no idea what the data looks like.

It's a lot more code (and a lot more options and control), but it is faster.  Where the `DataAdapter` approach took up to 30 secs this takes about 3 secs for 10k rows.  You *could* keep the code you have for SQL Server using the `DataReader` with the bulk loader, but that means processing the XLS files differently for one versus the other.  Since both will import from CSV, I'd do that.

Comment: Thank you for the time that you have spent on this I really appreciate it. I find it strange that MySQL has not made it easy to Import Excel Data files. the way that MSSQL has. the MSSQL Code I use it about 1 sec per 30k rows, really fast. That said I think I need to accept that CSV is the way to go. I will implement your code (Thank you). If I do stumble into an approach to get Excel into Bulk load with MySQL, I will post onto this thread. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: It is very much in Microsoft's interest to make 2 of their products work together. Now that you can upvote please do so.  Upvoting - clicking the UpArrow next to any post you find useful - helps other users find good answers.